# Custom ActionBar using setCustomView - inflated or not?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

For some reason, both of the two blocks of code below work, but they display the result slightly differently. Could someone explain the difference?

Version 1:

```
View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_test, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView ( customView );
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions ( ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM );
```

Version 2:

```
actionBar.setCustomView ( R.layout.custom_test );
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions ( ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first option you are inflating a view setting a null on parent root, which means that after you set it as the actionBar view, it doesnt inherit its root properties (padding/margin and other style params set on the android native), while on the second one you are not specifying a null parent so it inherits from native actionBar root style.